# Why Pod file can not find header files?

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods, header-files

I am using TWPhotoPickerController which is installed as a Pod file. I want to use this as a video trimming functionality. So I am adding SAVideoRangeSlider.h in this Pod file but it throws error that it cannot find it.

SAVideoRangeSlider cannot be installed as a Pod. I tried several solution listed on web with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Examine the command line options being passed to the compiler for this file (you want the `-I` options) and check that they include the directory where that header files exists. Then it will be a case of changing the *Header Search Path* in the build settings to fix.

Comment: English please? I'm a beginner. Thanks for your time btw